# Select data from a table while update is running within a transaction in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, transactions, locking

The following sql query is used to update a specific row inside transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

Update [dbo].[StudentExamAttendanceDetails]   SET StudentFeedBack = 1 Where Id = 4883174

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

The problem is until the transaction is committed the whole table remains locked. So I can not select any data from the same table at the same time.

For testing purpose, I ran the following portion of the query skipping the `COMMIT TRANSACTION;` part:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

Update [dbo].[StudentExamAttendanceDetails]   SET StudentFeedBack = 1 Where Id = 4883174
```

At the same time I ran the select query. As the whole table is locked, the select query can not select any data. When I run the commit code:
`COMMIT TRANSACTION;` on the update query then the select query is working. But I am trying to run the select query while the update transaction is not yet committed. That means I only want to lock the row that is being updated not the whole table.
So I tried two ways:

```
1. GO  
   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; 

2. Update [dbo].[StudentExamAttendanceDetails] With(RowLock)  SET StudentFeedBack = 1 
   Where Id = 4883174
```

But none of these methods is working. The whole table is still locked and I can not select any data from the table until the transaction is committed.

Comment: If you HAVE to return data while a row/table is locked, you have to do it on the `SELECT`. You can't run an `UPDATE` statement without locking a table/row. Note that using hints like `WITH (NOLOCK)` come with their own problems, so it's rarely best practice.

Comment: The entire table will not be locked by a singleton update if you have a unique index on `Id`. If you are missing that critical index (which should probably be the primary key), the entire table must be scanned and locked.

Comment: In addition to suggesting to create an index on the `id` column or even make it the primary key: why use an explicit transaction to update a single row in just one table?

Answer (score 0):

Just to ensure you got it correctly, the use of

```
GO SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

or

`WITH (NOLOCK)`

has to do with the select statement and not the update. Use of transaction will result in a lock either on the whole table or on the selected row, depending on the existence of an index. Try to make sure that WITH (NOLOCK) is used in the Read Script you are running.